# How to install mysql dynamically from within java?

Tags: java, installation

I am currently trying to create an installer for a application that i created. And i want the installer to be able to run on mac, windows and linux for now. Hence, i chose to make my installer in java.

Now, the problem that i am facing is i have to install mysql from within java without giving the user all those unnecessary choices during the setup phase because it really necessary for them to know it. I know this can be done because while installing wamp, this is how mysql is installed. I only need to bother the users for the right things.

So, can somebody tell me how it can be done?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Are you aware of the GPL license MySQL is distributed with? You aren't allowed to add MySQL in your installer. You need to ask your users to download and install it themselves.

Comment: I did not even consider that, thank you for bringing it to my attention. Guess i'll have to consider other options

Comment: @kgiannakakis - If Nishant's application and his installer are also GPL'ed then he *could* embed a binary MySQL installer in his installer.  It is a bad idea though ...

Comment: @kgiannakakis , You can ALLWAYS embed a binary installer for MySQL, you only need to provide the information that MySQL is GPLed and a link from where the source can be downloaded. It is a big misconception to believe you can not distribute GPLed binaries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might not be exactly what you're after, but how dependant are you on using mysql as the DBMS? If you use fairly standard SQL and this suits your application, maybe you could switch to Apache Derby? That will allow you to include the whole DB as a part of the installation, and completely invisible to the user.

See: http://db.apache.org/derby/

(caveat: I don't remember the details of the Apache license, but I'm assuming there's no issue there)

Answer (score 2):

For Mac and Linux I would let your installer start a shell script. However on Macs it is not common to have "installers". You should consider to just deliever binaries which the user can copy via drag&drop with his mouse. For that you usually only make an immage file (*dmg) which gets mounted by the finder and opens in its own finder window. You can have a symbolic link of the Applications folder on that *.dmg and a background image with some text: "drag here --->"